To solve the Integral $\int \frac{2^x-3^x}{2^x+3^x}dx$?
Can someone help me solve the integral
$$\int\dfrac{2^x-3^x}{2^x+3^x}dx$$
Could someone provide a step-by-step solution or suggest an effective method?
Thank you!

How do you use the substitution method? Can you edit by adding your workings? Thanks!

Can you show what substitutions you've tried? Edit your post to include this.

Why did you edit the question deleting some information about what you tried?

Simplify the fraction with $2^x$, change  $x$ to $x=2y\log_{3/2} e$ and yout integral will be proportional to $\int \tanh(y)dy$.

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{2^x-3^x}{2^x+3^x}dx &=\int\frac{2^x(1-\left(\frac32\right)^x)}{2^x(1+\left(\frac32\right)^x)}dx \\
& =\int\frac{1-\left(\frac32\right)^x}{1+\left(\frac32\right)^x}dx \\
& \stackrel{t=\left(\frac32\right)^x}=\frac{1}{\log \frac32} \int\frac{1-t}{1+t} \frac{dt}{t} \\
& =\frac{1}{\log \frac32}\left(\int\frac{1}{t}dt-2\int\frac{1}{1+t}dt\right) \\
& =x-2\frac{\log \left(1+\left(\frac32\right)^x\right)}{\log \frac32}+C \\
\end{align*}

factor $2^x$ then $u=(3/2)^x$, $du=\ln3/2\;u\;dx$
so you have to solve $\frac{1-u}{1+u}\frac1u=\frac1u-\frac2{1+u}$
$=\frac1{\ln3/2}[\ln u-2\ln (1+u)]=x-\frac2{\ln3/2}\ln(1+(3/2)^x)$
If i don't make a mistake
